# download attribute issues with <a>

Tags: html, anchor

I tried to make custom file name for user to download, however I can't seem to use `${}` with it.

What I'm trying to achieve is:

```
let foo = "name"
let fileName = `${name}footer.html`
<a download={filename} className="btn btn-info">Download</a>
```

Also this wont work:

```
<a download=`${name}footer.html` className="btn btn-info">Download</a>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Hello! If you have a solution, could you please post that as an answer instead of editing it into the question? Thanks!

Comment: By the way, could you post the code where you put the anchor element in the DOM? I see the filename being generated, and I see some HTML, but I don't see anything like `innerHTML = ` (or `$(myHtml).append(...)`). I strongly suspect the problem is coming from the code you haven't posted. You need to create a [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href=`${name}footer.html` download className="btn btn-info">Download</a>
```

Comment: It still wont allow me to edit href like that, getting syntax errors

Comment: In this case i need more code, im sure its just a little context thing (where you placed what).